# Determine a 4d vector $\langle N, D\rangle$ corresponding to the a plane with three points

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm having trouble understanding why i'm getting a different result than the book for the given problem.

> Determine a 4d vector $\langle N, D\rangle$ corresponding to the plane that passes through the three points $A = \langle 1, 2, 0 \rangle$, B =  $\langle 2, 0, -1 \rangle$, and $C = \langle 3, -2, -1 \rangle$
>
> The answer they have indicates that it is $\langle 2, 1, 0, -4 \rangle$

The steps i've take are as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\vec{AB} & = \langle B_x - A_x, B_y - A_y, B_z - A_z \rangle \\
& = \langle 2 - 1, 0 - 2, (-1) - 0 \rangle \\
& = \langle 1, - 2, -1 \rangle \\
\vec{AC} & = \langle C_x - A_x, C_y - A_y, C_z - A_z \rangle \\
& = \langle 3 - 1, (-2) - 2, (-1) - 0 \rangle \\
& = \langle 2, - 4, -1 \rangle
\end{align}$$

Identify the Normal Vector (N)
$$ \begin{align}
N & = \vec{AB} \times \vec{AC} \\
& = \begin{vmatrix}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\
1 & -2 & -1 \\
2 & -4 & -1
\end{vmatrix} \\
& = \hat{i}(((-2)\cdot(-1)) - ((-1)\cdot(-4))) + \hat{j}((-1\cdot2) - (1\cdot(-1))) + \hat{k}((1\cdot(-4)) - ((-2)\cdot2)) \\
& = \hat{i}(-2) + \hat{j}(-1) + \hat{k}(0) \\
& = \langle-2, -1, 0\rangle
\end{align}$$

Identify the perpendicular distance (D)
$$\begin{align}
D & = -N\cdot A \\
& = -\begin{bmatrix}-2, -1, 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 2 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} \\
& = 2\cdot1 + 1\cdot2 + 0 \cdot 0 \\
& = 4
\end{align}$$

Which results in $ \langle N, D\rangle = \langle -2, -1, 0, 4 \rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that a non-zero scalar multiple of a homogeneous coordinate vector is equivalent to it. The answer you came up with only differs from the key’s in its sign, that is, it differs by a factor of $-1$, so your answer matches. In effect, what you’re doing is finding the coefficients of an equation of the form $ax+by+cz+d=0$ that all three points satisfy. Multiplying both sides of this equation by a non-zero constant doesn’t affect its solution set.

If you’re familiar with row-reduction, a.k.a., Gaussian elimination, then you can find the vector that represents the plane directly by assembling the homogeneous 4-vectors of the points as the rows of a matrix and computing its null space. Specifically, $$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0&1\\2&0&-1&1\\3&-2&-1&1\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\frac12\\0&1&0&\frac14\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ from which you can read that the homogeneous null vector is $\left[\frac12:\frac14:0:-1\right] = [2:1:0:-4]$.

Comment: thank you, that makes so much sense.  I can't believe i didn't remember that.

Comment: @Nuku If you had done $N = \vec{AC} \times \vec{AB}$ instead, you would’ve gotten the same answer as in the key.